# Unable to See cart on top Right corner of Demo Venia Store

Tags: magento, e-commerce, aem, aem-6

I am unable to see the mini cart on top right corner after creating a new project using demo-store.all-0.9.0.zip from latest release here https://github.com/adobe/aem-cif-project-archetype/releases and installing it through package manager in my AEM 6.5. Do I need to install it separately? I am following this integration through https://www.adobe.io/apis/experiencecloud/commerce-integration-framework/getting-started.html

Comment: Did you check for any errors in the log while installing the package?

Answer (score 0):

Cart will not be even visible until and unless you do not setup a dispatcher as shown here in this [video](https://www.adobe.io/apis/experiencecloud/commerce-integration-framework/tutorials.html#!AdobeDocs/commerce-cif-documentation/master/tutorials/03-shopping-cart-dispatcher.md). The mini cart is actually a react component which directly communicates with Back-end Magento and to avoid CORS issue you have to set up proxy through a Dispatcher.